# How to keep LocationManager running in the background?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to write a tracing app, which needs to get location data and represent it on a map. The app works fine, when it is on screen, but when it if off-screen or the phone is locked, it will not receive and location updates. What can do I to keep it updating, even when the phone is locked?

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

...

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2500,5, locationListenerGPS);

...

LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {

        LatLongLastKnownPos = LatLongCurrentPos;
        LatLongCurrentPos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if ( isMapReady ) { updateMap(); }

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
};
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits ? Recent versions of Android have become very fussy about always-on location updates. In Android 10 and above there is a specific permission for this, but it's kind-of frowned on in general. Because it's such a privacy hazard, there's the potential that Android will disallow it completely in future.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement this.

Comment: maybe some kind of startForegroundService() might be a good idea?